# Regression: OpenID login triggers NoScript XSS protection

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid

Yesterday, I was able to log in to my stackexchange account using my OpenID with no problems.  Today, it triggers NoScript's XSS protection, and fails.  I suspect this is a regression caused by an OpenID-related [bug fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261832/unable-to-add-livejournal-login/262010) that was deployed earlier today.

Firefox 39.0
NoScript 2.6.9.34
OpenID provider: launchpad.net

Comment: The fix deployed only touched adding a new login credential. Nothing changed for *logging in* between yesterday and today. I'll try out Launchpad + NoScript tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: What are your NoScript settings? Which of our domains have you whitelisted, if any?

Comment: NoScript default settings, plus Allow Scripts Globally. (I use NoScript mainly for XSS and clickjacking protection, not for disabling javascript.)

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ any luck yet??

Comment: Nope. It's still broken.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ Still broken? Can anyone else confirm or help?

Comment: ps: ʇsәɹoɈ - **please prepend @username** in your replies, else the user won't be notified...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty : still broken.

Comment: I have the same problem here.

Comment: @Adam any updates?

Comment: Shadow Wizard, I don't know if @ tagging works here when there's a space in the username, but if it does, you probably have to use the whole username to get Adam's attention, like this: @Adam Lear

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* a real fix, only a work-around (good enough for doing the OpenID login):

- *temporarily* (!) **disable XSS** like so:

[image]

- **then do the OpenID login** (worked for me)
- and finally **turn XSS back on right after**.

<sub>Not sure if both checkboxes need to be (un)ticked or if one of them would suffice -- I (un)ticked both of them.</sub>

Comment: It's probably enough to add an entry to the "Anti-XSS Protection Exceptions" list below those checkboxes. However, since I haven't managed to reproduce this bug myself, I can't test this, or suggest a suitable entry.

Comment: Just unchecking the first box worked for me. Adding launchpad.net as an exception (using the pattern `^https://login\.launchpad\.net/\+OPENid\?`) did **not** work. I should probably sign out and try some variations on that pattern...

Comment: I've now had success with the pattern `^https?://login\.launchpad\.net/\+[Oo][Pp][Ee][Nn][Ii][Dd]\?`. I don't know which of the changes were necessary, though.

Comment: Adding only @TimPederick line to the whitelist worked for me, allowed me to login on this site and add this very comment.